# Pass a conditional as an argument in Swift?

Tags: swift

I was thinking of abstracting some conditional logic in my application. Suppose I have two functions in this simplified example:

```
func1(val1: Int, val2: Int, threshold: Int) -> Bool {
  return (val1 == threshold && val2 == threshold)
}

func2(val: Int, thresholdHi: Int, thresholdLo: Int) {
  return (val < thresholdHi && val > thresholdLo)
}
```

My idea is to make a function that performs a conditional check on a set of values.

```
funcIdea(vals[Int], conditional: ???) -> Bool {
  for val in vals {
    if !conditional(val) { return false; }
  }
  return true
}
func1(...){
  return funcIdea([val1, val2], ???)
}
```

I think this is possible with either a closure or a function.

Comment: This would require a closure just like Array `filter` or `contains`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with a closure.

```
func funcIdea(vals: [Int], conditional: (Int)->Bool) -> Bool {
    for val in vals {
        if !conditional(val) { return false; }
    }
    return true
}

func func1(val1: Int, val2: Int, threshold: Int) -> Bool {
    //return (val1 == threshold && val2 == threshold)
    return funcIdea(vals: [val1, val2], conditional: { (val) -> Bool in
        return val > threshold
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a closure to your function, then you can use `contains(where:)` to check if the closure is true for all elements of the array. The double negation is necessary to allow for an early exit in `contains(where:)`.

```
extension Array {
    func allElementsSatisfy(_ condition: (Element)->(Bool)) -> Bool {
        return !self.contains(where: { !condition($0)})
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call it on any Array like this:

```
[1,2,3].allElementsSatisfy({$0 < 1}) // false
[1,2,3].allElementsSatisfy({$0 < 4}) // true
["a","b","c"].allElementsSatisfy({$0.count == 1}) // true
["a","b","c"].allElementsSatisfy({$0.count > 1}) // false
```